# Why are Java LocalTime and OffsetTime values incorrect when viewed directly on database

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime, timezone, java-time

Application server (JVM) running in time zone: `Europe/Dublin` - `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()`

Time zone for JDBC connections set for Spring / Hibernate using the configuration property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

Java Entity:

```
@Column(name = "local_time")
private LocalTime localTime;

@Column(name = "local_date_time")
private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

@Column(name = "offset_time")
private OffsetTime offsetTime;
```

Java values debugged on application server (JVM) ..

`LocalTime` - `time` SQL type:

```
// LocalTime.ofInstant(now, Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone())
01:32:13.283256
```

`LocalDateTime` - `timestamp` SQL type:

```
// LocalDateTime.ofInstant(now, Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone())
2022-12-06T01:32:13.283256
```

`OffsetTime` - `time with time zone` SQL type:

```
// OffsetTime.ofInstant(now, Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone())
01:32:13.283256Z
```

Database configured to use UTC:

```
postgres=# select name, setting, source from pg_settings where name='TimeZone';
   name   | setting |       source       
----------+---------+--------------------
 TimeZone | Etc/UTC | configuration file
```

Query database (PostgreSQL) for values:

```
select * from item;

 id | local_time |      local_date_time       | offset_time
----+------------+----------------------------+-------------
  1 | 00:32:13   | 2022-12-06 01:32:13.283256 | 00:32:13+00
```

Why are the column values for `local_time` and `offset_time` 1 hour behind UTC? Shouldn't they be the same as `local_date_time` i.e `01:32` rather than `00:32`

`local_date_time` is the only column with correct value when directly querying the database. Why is that?

Comment: Since a time value has no date associated with it, there's no way of telling whether daylight savings time is in effect, so it is not taken into account.

Comment: Using e.g. `\d+ item`, what's the column type of `local_time`, `local_date_time`, and `offset_time`?

Comment: @rzwitserloot The database types for each column are already outlined in the question for `local_time`, `local_date_time` and `offset_time`

Comment: It seems to be a bug. Instead of waiting for an answer (which can be simply based on guesses), you should raise a ticket with the Postgresql community and/or support team.

Comment: Seems like the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74717698/why-is-java-localtime-013213-283256-stored-as-time-003213-in-database-1-hou/74789263#74789263, as Robby Cornelissen alluded to above.  Maybe I missed something.  :-)

Comment: **Missing information…** You need to show us the *exact* structure of your `item` table. And you need to show us *exactly* how you wrote the row of data shown in your Question. And you need to explain *exactly* how you ran that query, in what tool, along with the **current default time zone in the database session** used by that tool. Far too little info here for us to explain the behavior.