# Hour of LocalTime & OffsetTime are not persisted correctly using Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc, timezone, hibernate-mapping

I pushed a minimal example on GitHub which you can test [here](https://github.com/jbcbezerra/hibernate-examples).

In the example you can see that i am trying to persist an Entity with LocalTime and OffsetTime properties. But a time of 15:30 get persisted as 14:30 for LocalTime and 14:30 - Offset for OffsetTime.

they discussed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74717698/why-is-java-localtime-013213-283256-stored-as-time-003213-in-database-1-hou/77289799#77289799) but did not come up with a proper solution since if someone would look into the database they would read a time of 14:30 which would actually be wrong. Has someone a idea how to fix this?

The important parts of my Setup are as follows:

Postgres Docker Container via Compose-File:

```yaml
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:15.2-alpine'
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      TZ: UTC
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all"]
```

The Entity:

```
@Entity
public class TimeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(15,30,30);
    private OffsetTime offsetTime = OffsetTime.of(15,30,30,0,ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"));
    private OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(2023,1,1,15,30,30,0, ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"));

}
```

I also have set the Spring properties for Hibernate timezone to UTC: `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
```

And when persisting the entity, hibernate logs following insert statement:

```
insert 
    into
        time_entity
        (local_time,offset_date_time,offset_time,id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,?)
2023-10-13T19:45:47.659+02:00 TRACE 246595 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [TIME] - [15:30:30]
2023-10-13T19:45:47.659+02:00 TRACE 246595 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP_UTC] - [2023-01-01T15:30:30+02:00]
2023-10-13T19:45:47.659+02:00 TRACE 246595 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [3] as [TIME_UTC] - [15:30:30+02:00]
2023-10-13T19:45:47.659+02:00 TRACE 246595 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

whereas the postgres container logs following insert statement:

```
insert into time_entity (local_time,offset_date_time,offset_time,id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2023-10-13T17:45:47.661272468Z 2023-10-13 17:45:47.661 UTC [511] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '14:30:30', $2 = '2023-01-01 14:30:30+01', $3 = '12:30:30', $4 = '1'
```

Comment: FYI: `OffsetTime` as a concept makes no sense. Without a date, a time-of-day plus offset equals nonsense. (Just think about it.)  This class exists in Java only to comply with the SQL standard. That standard briefly declares that type but neglects to explain what is the world they meant it to do. Notice in the Postgres documentation how they say this type should be avoided.

Comment: Looks like you switched the order of the four fields while composing your Question. Please take more care when posting here.